# Не получается присвоить значение по индексу для массива указателей

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, типы-данных

```
 typedef void (*uType_fp)(void);
 static uType_fp dpQueue;
 dpQueue = (uType_fp)(malloc(dynQueueLength * (sizeof(uType_fp))));
 dpQueue[i] = 0;
```

Получаю ошибку

```
expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Как у вас определен `dpQueue`? и `uType_fp`?

Comment: Добавил в описание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы объявили массив. Ему нельзя присваивать адрес другого массива!

Более того - если у вас **уже** есть массив - зачем вы выделяете память заново - динамически?

После внесения изменений в вопрос...

Вот как нужно:

```
typedef void (*uType_fp)(void);
uType_fp * dpQueue;
dpQueue = (uType_fp*)(malloc(dynQueueLength * (sizeof(uType_fp))));
dpQueue[i] = 0;
```

Вы создаете массив указателей на функции - значит, тип переменной `dpQueue` - указатель на этот тип, который вы будете хранить - на указатель на функцию.

Comment: Айййй, не оттуда описание, извиняюсь, снова изменил.

Comment: Опять же - забыли сделать **указателем**. См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Все, спасибо решено.

Comment: http://ideone.com/1ObPEY

Comment: Вы хотите хранить указатели на функции - так? Те самые типы `uType_fp`. Значит, в каждом `dpQueue[i]` будет лежать `uType_fp`. Значит, тип `dpQueue` - как указателя на первый элемент массива элементов `uType_fp` - будет указатель на `uType_fp`, т.е. `uType_fp*`.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, все понял.